# How to use setasign fpdi v2.0.0 in Laravel 5.2.* or higher?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, controller, fpdf, fpdi

I want to edit some pdf file with setasign fpdi,
When it was fpdi still in version 1.6.* i use this way to use it :
I install it via composer

```
composer require setasign/fpdf & composer require setasign/fpdi
```

And i use it in Laravel controller :

```
$pdf = new \FDPI();
$pdf->setSourceFile('PATH/TO/SOURCEFILE');
$pdf->Output();
```

It work for fpdi version 1.6.* (Legacy)

But when i use the fpdi v2.0.0 and i call the fpdi class in controller using

```
$pdf = new \FPDI();
```

it give an error message "Could find FPDI class" from Laravel

Any advice on how to use fpdi v2.0.0 in Laravel5?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Version 2 uses namespaces:

```
$pdf = new \setasign\Fpdi\Fpdi();
```

A full migration guide is available [here](https://manuals.setasign.com/fpdi-manual/v2/migrating/).

Comment: ah i see,
i didn't recognize the namespace.
Thank you for the solution.